# How to auto start docker when synology restart

Tags: docker, synology

When you restart your Synology Nas The docker container stops.
Tell us how you can be restarted automatically turn on the docker container.

Comment: If you run your docker container from command line, you can set it to restart automatically. See https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=101241

Answer (score 9):

For existing containers you can find the "Enable auto-restart" setting under Docker > Container > Edit > General Setttings.

**The container must be stopped to edit the settings.**

Comment: Wow, that was hard to find ;) Ty

Answer (score 4):

When launching an image in Docker > Image, you can find "Enable auto-restart" behind the "Advanced Settings" button.